# Plugin with id 'org.sonarqube' not found

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to implement sonar with gradle for code-coverage measure for my project. 
we are using gradle-4.0.1 and sonarqube-6.4 .

when I run gradle sonarqube from command line I get this error-

```
Plugin with id 'org.sonarqube' not found.
```

I tried few code changes but no luck, please help.
My build.gradle file is as below-

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"


sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.projectName","Spring4WebService Code Coverage Demo"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "org.sonarqubeJacocoCodeCoverage"
    property "sonar.reportPath" , "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
  }
}


test{
  ignoreFailures = true
}


ext {
    jacocoVersion = '0.7.6.201602180812'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDir "src/main/java"
  test.java.srcDir "src/test/java"
}

springBoot {
  mainClass = "com.concretepage.config.WebAppInitializer"
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web','com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

jacoco{
  toolVersion = "${jacocoVersion}"
}

jacocoTestReport {
 reports{
  html.enabled=true
  xml.enabled=true
  csv.enabled=true
 }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just like the `'org.springframework.boot'` plugin, the `'org.sonarqube'` plugin does not belong to Gradle. It is a third-party plugin, so you need to add it as a `buildscript` dependency:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5"
    }
}
```

Now `apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve this after adding settings.gradle file in project root with

```
pluginManagement {
repositories {
    maven { url "<Repo_URL>" }
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it looks like:

```
plugins {
   id 'groovy'
   id 'application'
   id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.0'
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

sonarqube {
   properties {
      property "sonar.host.url", "http://sonarqube:9000"
      property "sonar.sources", "src"
   }
}

tasks['sonarqube'].dependsOn test
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the plugins DSL specifying a full version (e.g., `id "org.sonarqube" version "3.5.0.2730"` instead of `id "org.sonarqube" version "3.5.0"`) in the `plugins` section of build.gradle resolved this issue for me.

Here are examples for plugins DSL and legacy plugin application: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube

Answer (score 0):

**1) Using the plugins DSL:**

```
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "4.0.0.2929"
}
```

Or,

**2) Using legacy plugin application:**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:4.0.0.2929"
  }
}
```

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"